# Building Ruby 1.8.7 with --enable-load-relative

Tags: ruby, rvm

I know the --enable-load-relative flag works with Ruby 1.9.3 and higher. But it doesn't seem to have any effect on Ruby 1.8.7. Is it possible to build 1.8.7 such that the paths are not hardcoded? I'm trying to build Ruby on one machine and then copy the installation to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can always calculate from the current path.

```
SCRIPT_DIR = File.dirname(__FILE__)
require "#{SCRIPT_DIR}/../lib/thingy"
```

Comment: I can, but I already have a bunch of scripts which do "require thingy" and I would ideally like to not change them.